# Get ComboBox selected value from a list which has two types of objects and the combobox is only showing one of them

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm building a C# application in Windows Forms.
I have a vehicle class and two derived classes car and motorbike.
I then have the vehicles saved into a list.

Now I have a form where I want to show only the cars or only the motorbikes. In a main form there is a button "show cars" and another button "show motorbikes" and they will tell the other form which to list ("type" variable in code below).

In the show form I have a combobox which will show all the cars or motorbikes (only one, not both) that exist and when selecting one, there are textboxes that will show the info from that one.

To populate the combobox I use:

```
foreach (Vehicle V in GetVehiclesList())
{
    if (type == "Car")
    {
        if (V.WhatIsIt() == "Car")
        {
            combobox.Items.Add(V.GetVehicleName());
        }
    }
    else if (type == "Motorbike")
    {
        if (V.WhatIsIt() == "Motorbike")
        {
            combobox.Items.Add(V.GetVehicleName());
        }
    }
}
```

Note: WhatIsIt() returns a string with the class' name.

**Now the problem is to get the selected vehicle in the combobox to show the info from that vehicle.**

If I wanted to show all the vehicles, I would use this:

```
private void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VehicleToShow = GetVehiclesList()[combobox.SelectedIndex];
    vehicle_name_textbox.Text = VehicleToShow.GetVehicleName();
    // and goes on
}
```

What this does is it gets the index number of the combobox item selected and goes get the vehicle in the list with that same position number. 
It works because the vehicles are added to the combobox with same position/index as in the list.
Therefore, it doesn't work for displaying only one of them (car or motorbike) because the position number in list will fail to be equal to the index in combobox.

So I used the folowing approach:

```
private void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VehicleToShow = null;
    int carposition = 0;
    int motorbikeposition = 0;
    int comboboxindex = combobox.SelectedIndex;

    foreach (Vehicle V in GetVehiclesList())
    {
        if (V.WhatIsIt() == "Car")
        {
            if (carposition == comboboxindex)
            {
                VehicleToShow = V;
            }
            else
            {
                carposition++;
            }
        }
        else if (V.WhatIsIt() == "Motorbike")
        {
            if (motorbikeposition == comboboxindex)
            {
                VehicleToShow = V;
            }
            else
            {
                motorbikeposition++;
            }
        }
    }

    vehicle_name_textbox.Text = VehicleToShow.GetVehicleName();
    // and goes on
}
```

While this seems to me to be something that should work, when using it, it won't display the info from the vehicle selected in the combobox.

How can I get it to work?

Note: Placing each vehicle type in a different list is not an option. Also, searching list for an object with same name as selected value is not best option since it won't work properly if it has two vehicles with same name. Ideally it would be something similar as the approach I tried to use.

Comment: Don't put names in the combo list.  Put the actual class.  Then you don't have to do all this position look up stuff that is spaghetti code — which leads to bugs in your future.

Comment: You mean put "Car" and "Motorbike" values in the combobox? The thing is that the form will show info individually, so there must be a single vehicle selected.
Sorry if I misunderstood what you meant, I'm not very advanced in this yet. And thanks for your reply.

Comment: You put `V` in the combo box.  You didn't show us your class code, but you would have to override the ToString property and just return the Name.

Comment: you don't need this `V.WhatIsIt() == "Car"`, just make `Car` and `Motorbike` classes to inherit from `Vehicle`, populate a collection of Vehicle with instances of Car and Motorbike and then `if (V.GetType() == typeof(Car)) { //handle cars }`

Comment: Thanks for your advice @derloopkat I didn't know of this when I wrote the code but I already read something about it afterwards and I will look into it to know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the *names* of your objects to the list. Add *the actual objects themselves* instead; then `combobox.SelectedItem` immediately contains everything you need without requiring *any* lookup at all, since it'll be the full object.

The filling of the data:

```
this.combobox.Items.Clear();
foreach (Vehicle veh in this.GetVehiclesList())
{
    // assuming "type" is a string variable filled up by some other selected value.
    if (!String.Equals(type, typeof(veh).ToString()))
        continue;
    this.combobox.Items.Add(veh);
}
```

Though derloopkat's suggestion of saving `type` as an actual `Type` so you can compare them directly is probably more efficient than string compares. Avoid string compares in code; they are often an ugly programmer shortcut for something that can be done way more elegantly and efficiently internally.

To make them show up in the list correctly, simply add the `ToString()` function in your vehicle class that returns the actual vehicle name:

```
public override String ToString()
{
    return this.GetVehicleName()
}
```

And finally, to retrieve the selected object and update your UI:

```
private void combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // "as" is a "try cast": if the object is not the expected type it will become null.
    this.VehicleToShow = this.combobox.SelectedItem As Vehicle;
    if (this.VehicleToShow == null)
        return; // maybe add code to clear UI
    this.vehicle_name_textbox.Text = this.VehicleToShow.GetVehicleName();
    // fill in the rest
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is much better this way using SelectedItem. I expected something like this to exist, just didn't know how to actually use it. It's actually dumb to do it the way I was doing, populating strings to the combobox (it was what I was thought though).

Comment: So, I did as you adviced and it's working perfectly now. I just didn't use the "this" and the "if" that you used when populating the combobox (I will keep the way I have this time). Why did you use "this"? Is it important? Can there be cases where the "this" is really necessary?

Comment: Another quick question just to clarify, when we add an object to the combobox, it will use object.ToString() as the value to show in the dropdown, correct? Therefore the need to add the ToString() function in the class.

Comment: Ah, the `this.` is just a personal preference. It generally refers to a global class variables (and functions), as opposed to local function variables. It makes more clear what refers to local things inside the same class.

Comment: Yes, the `ComboBox` will indeed take the `.ToString()` representation of any object you put into it. Very often, for classes where you can't control its default `.ToString()` behaviour (original framework types like an `Encoding` or a `DateTime`, or classes from external dlls you may use), it is common practice to write a little wrapper class in which you can store your object and write a `.ToString()` that makes a string of the object exactly like you want it, or you just store the object _and_ a string, to set it to any string you want. That way you can still get the original object out.

Comment: Note, you can also set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` of the combo box to specify what to use as shown string and as `SelectedValue`, but it always felt ugly to me to specify property names as string, and on a lot of types there is no guarantee that a property for a decent string representation actually exists.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. Regards.